# Можно ли программно определить наличие звука в динамиках?

Tags: python, windows, аудио

Есть ли способ определить проигрывается звук в Windows или нет?
Без захвата аудио через микрофон.

Comment: Я припоминаю два параметра. 1)Чек - подключено что-нибудь в разьем аудио или нет (надо поискать это). 2) Галочка "выключить звук" и положение рычага громкости (обычная библиотека звука).  Правда... не факт что динамики включены в сеть - это уже не узнаем. Имеется ввиду эти данные програмно считать?

Comment: имеется в виду вообще пригрывается что ни будь в данный момент или нет

Comment: Если вы знаете, как работать с COM в Python, можно получить PeakValue с [IAudioMeterInformation](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/endpointvolume/nn-endpointvolume-iaudiometerinformation) для устройства по умолчанию. Оно будет ненулевое, если что-то воспроизводится. Вот пример на С++: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/CoreAudio/peak-meters

Comment: MSDN.WhiteKnight, спаибо за наводку.